# Makefile w/ bash completion: bash completion fails to tab expand makefile phony targets

Tags: bash, makefile, bash-completion

I am running a debian docker image on windows for development purposes with bash completion and build essential installed.

Typically, I instrument out a project with mini-scripts of repeated functionality via the makefile `.PHONY` target system.  With `bash-completion`, I usually get a `<tab>-<tab>` expansion of the `.PHONY` targets.

Since this tab expansion is failing (I just get a listing of files in the directory), it seems like I am missing some installation or enabling step on the Docker image.

How do I hook `bash-completion` up to make such that the `make <tab> <tab>` operation expands the `.PHONY` targets rather than the files in the directory?

Comment: People here want to help but you should show a  Minimal, Reproducible Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RogelioPrieto the problem with that is: if I could reproduce it minimally, I would be able to answer it myself.  I think expecting to be able to answer a question this esoteric outright is unreasonable.  I would accept an answer that merely advises on what directions to look into to fix this